# Why does Canvas's putImageData not work when I specify target location?

Tags: html, canvas

In trying to find documentation for Canvas context's putImageData() method, I've found things like this:

context.putImageData(imgData,x,y,dirtyX,dirtyY,dirtyWidth,dirtyHeight);

(from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_putimagedata.asp)

According to the documentation I've read, x and y are an index into the *source* image, whereas dirtyX and dirtyY specify coordinates in the target canvas where to draw the image. Yet, as you'll see from the example below (and JSFiddle) a call to putImageData(imgData,x,y) works while putImageData(imgData, 0, 0, locX, locY) doesn't. I'm not sure why.

**EDIT:**

I guess my real question is why the top row of the image is black, and there are only 7 rows, not 8. The images should start at the top-left of the Canvas. They DO start at the left (and have 8 columns). Why do they not start at the top?

**Answer:** that's due to divide by 0 on this line when yLoc is 0:

```
xoff = imgWidth / (yLoc/3);
```

**The JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/WZynM/

**Code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Canvas tutorial</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var canvas;
            var context; // The canvas's 2d context

            function setupCanvas()
            {
                canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                if (canvas.getContext)
                {
                    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    context.fillStyle = "black";    // this is default anyway
                    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                }
            }

            function init()
            {
                loadImages();
                startGating();
            }

            var images = new Array();
            var gatingTimer;
            var curIndex, imgWidth=0, imgHeight;

                // Load images
            function loadImages()
            {
                for (n = 1; n <= 16; n++)
                {
                    images[n] = new Image();
                    images[n].src = "qxsImages/frame" + n + ".png";
                //  document.body.appendChild(images[n]);

                    console.log("width = " + images[n].width + ", height = " + images[n].height);
                }

                curIndex = 1;
                imgWidth = images[1].width;
                imgHeight = images[1].height;
            }

            function redrawImages()
            {
                if (imgWidth == 0)
                    return;

                curIndex++;
                if (curIndex > 16)
                    curIndex = 1;

                    // To do later: use images[1].width and .height to layout based on image size
                for (var x=0; x<8; x++)
                {
                    for (var y=0; y<8; y++)
                    {
                        //if (x != 1)
                    //      context.drawImage(images[curIndex], x*150, y*100);
                        //  context.drawImage(images[curIndex], x*150, y*100, imgWidth/2, imgHeight/2); // scale
                    //  else
                            self.drawCustomImage(x*150, y*100);
                    }
                }
            }

            function drawCustomImage(xLoc, yLoc)
            {
                    // create a new pixel array
                imageData = context.createImageData(imgWidth, imgHeight);

                pos = 0; // index position into imagedata array
                xoff = imgWidth / (yLoc/3); // offsets to "center"
                yoff = imgHeight / 3;

                for (y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++) 
                {
                    for (x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++) 
                    {
                        // calculate sine based on distance
                        x2 = x - xoff;
                        y2 = y - yoff;
                        d = Math.sqrt(x2*x2 + y2*y2);
                        t = Math.sin(d/6.0);

                        // calculate RGB values based on sine
                        r = t * 200;
                        g = 125 + t * 80;
                        b = 235 + t * 20;

                        // set red, green, blue, and alpha:
                        imageData.data[pos++] = Math.max(0,Math.min(255, r));
                        imageData.data[pos++] = Math.max(0,Math.min(255, g));
                        imageData.data[pos++] = Math.max(0,Math.min(255, b));
                        imageData.data[pos++] = 255; // opaque alpha
                    }
                }

                    // copy the image data back onto the canvas
                context.putImageData(imageData, xLoc, yLoc);        // Works... kinda
            //  context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0, xLoc, yLoc, imgWidth, imgHeight);  // Doesn't work. Why?
            }


            function startGating()
            {
                gatingTimer = setInterval(redrawImages, 1000/25); // start gating
            }

            function stopGating()
            {
                clearInterval(gatingTimer);
            }
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body onload="setupCanvas(); init();">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1200" height="800"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WZynM/

Comment: What should be shown? Running the example here, I got a black background with some blue images with white circles inside them. Could you post an image with the expected result (or something close to it)?

Comment: The top row of the image is black, but should have some of the blue/white images in it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just had your coordinates backwards.

```
context.putImageData(imageData, xLoc, yLoc, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/WZynM/3/)**

`xLoc`, and `yLoc` are where you are putting it, and `0,0,imgWidth,imgHeight` is the data you are putting onto the canvas.

**[Another example](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/cVkg3/)** showing this.

A lot of the online docs seem a bit contradictory but for the seven param version

```
putImageData(img, dx, dy, dirtyX, dirtyY, dirtyRectWidth, dirtyRectHeight)
```

the dx, and dy are your destination, the next four params are the dirty rect parameters, basically controlling *what* you are drawing *from* the source canvas. One of the most thorough descriptions I can find was in the book HTML5 Unleashed by Simon Sarris (pg. 165).

Comment: Thanks. Follow-up question then: why do I have a row of black at the top of my canvas? The first calls to putImageData() specify 0,0 as the dx and dy locations. So the top-most row *should* have blue/white images in it, but instead it's black. (And you'll notice there are only 7 rows vertically, where there should be 8.) Got any idea why?

Comment: @VernJensen That's because of this line `xoff = imgWidth / (yLoc / 3);` division by 0 is throwing off the whole top row, nothing to do with `putImageData` fortunately. http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/WZynM/5/ I changed it to `xoff = imgWidth/3` just to illustrate.

Comment: Thanks! Found the same thing just now myself before even seeing your post. ;-)

Comment: as someone who owns this book: I can verify that you should get it and read it.

Comment: WARNING: The W3Shools documentation here:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_putimagedata.asp

documents this incorrectly, given what has been said above. I was misled by this when doing a check on the method synopsis. More complete answer to follow.

Comment: wow, I was reading "Height of the rectangle to be painted" to mean that it was *scaling* the image into that height, which is totally *not* what it does.

Answer (score 7):

Having been using this recently, I've discovered that Loktar above has hit upon a VERY important issue. Basically, some documentation of this method online is incorrect, a particularly dangerous example being W3Schools, to which a number of people will turn to for reference.

Their documentation states the following:

**Synopsis:**

- context.putImageData(imgData,x,y,dirtyX,dirtyY,dirtyWidth,dirtyHeight);

**Arguments:**

- imgData: Specifies the ImageData object to put back onto the canvas
- x : The x-coordinate, in pixels, of the upper-left corner of the ImageData object [WRONG]
- y : The y-coordinate, in pixels, of the upper-left corner of the ImageData object [WRONG]
- dirtyX : Optional. The horizontal (x) value, in pixels, where to place the image on the canvas [WRONG]
- dirtyY : Optional. The vertical (y) value, in pixels, where to place the image on the canvas [WRONG]
- dirtyWidth : Optional. The width to use to draw the image on the canvas
- dirtyHeight: Optional. The height to use to draw the image on the canvas

As Loktar states above, the CORRECT synopsis is as follows:

**Correct Synopsis:**

- context.putImageData(imgData, canvasX, canvasY, srcX ,srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight);

**Arguments:**

- imgData: Specifies the ImageData object to put back onto the canvas (as before);
- canvasX : The x coordinate of the location on the CANVAS where you are plotting your imageData;
- canvasY : The y coordinate of the location on the CANVAS where you are plotting your ImageData;
- srcX : Optional. The x coordinate of the top left hand corner of your ImageData;
- srcY : Optional. The y coordinate of the top left hand corner of your ImageData;
- srcWidth : Optional. The width of your ImageData;
- srcHeight : Optional. The height of your ImageData.

Use the **correct synopsis** above, and you won't have the problems that have been encountered above.

I'll give a big hat tip to Loktar for finding this out initially, but I thought it apposite to provide an expanded answer in case others run into the same problem.

Comment: Thanks David, very clarifying